# how to get two domain names to point to the same web app and show different content?

Tags: java, web-applications, amazon-web-services

I have two clients, each one is a restaurant website of near identical design.

There's a main page, a menu page, a contact us page, and so on.

I'd like to build this in Java probably running on Tomcat or GlassFish on my own Amazon AWS virtual machine.

My question is, if I have one web application at:

```
1.2.3.4/myapp
```

where

```
1.2.3.4/myapp?clientid=1
```

shows Restaurant A's web site, and

```
1.2.3.4/myapp?clientid=2
```

shows Restaurant B's web site

How do I set things up so:

`www.restaurantA.com` shows the content of `1.2.3.4/myapp?clientid=1`

and

`www.restaurantB.com` shows the content of `1.2.3.4/myapp?clientid=2`

?

Any suggestions or ideas are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you considered using one EC2 instance per website? You could create a base AMI and then create instances from that, and each would get its own elastic IP.

Comment: @smcg Thanks for the suggestion, but what I want is one application running on one server with two fully database driven web sites.  That way I can add more clients without having to add more servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want one single webapp to serve different content depending on the originating URL, you can simple use a `javax.servlet.Filter`. First declare the filter in `web.xml`:

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>DomainNameFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>com.whatever.blah.DomainNameFilter</filter-class>
</filter>   

 <filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>DomainNameFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Then create a class called `DomainNameFilter` that implements `javax.servlet.Filter`. In the `doFilter()` method, you can grab the originating URL like this:

```
request.getServerName()
```

Remember to also call `chain.doFilter(request, response);` if you are using any other filters. Now that you know the originating domain name, you can build the appropriate response. I've done this by setting domain-specific attributes in the `doFilter()` method like this:

```
request.setAttribute("title", titleMap.get(request.getServerName()));
```

where `titleMap` is a `HashMap` that is loaded from a DB in the `Filter`'s `init()` method. To use the value in a JSP for example, you would access it like this:

```
<title><%=request.getAttribute("title")%></title>
```

If you want to see a working example, check out http://thermodynamiccomputing.org/ and http://fnode.xeiam.com/. Both theses website are actually the same exact webapp using the filtering technique which I just described.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution in `Tomcat` that I currently have deployed. Rather than use `?clientid=1` and `?clientid=2`, you can configure your `server.xml` file to pass the requests to a particular web app depending on the source `IP` address. In `server.xml`:

```
<Host name="www.restaurantA.com"  
    appBase="restaurantA"
    unpackWARs="true" 
    autoDeploy="true">
</Host>
<Host name="www.restaurantB.com"  
    appBase="restaurantB"
    unpackWARs="true" 
    autoDeploy="true">
</Host>
```

Then in `$TOMCAT_HOME/`, alongside `webapps` create two folders called `restaurantA` and `restaurantB`. Deploy your webapps as `ROOT.war` in the correct folder and restart `Tomcat`. This solution is much cleaner in my opinion, and it completely separates the web applications from each other.

Comment: @Mihai Thanks for the info, very useful.  However ideally I'd like to just have one web app running that can serve content for multiple websites.